# OpenPyXL always return None for a cell with hyperlink

Tags: xlrd, openpyxl, xlwt, xlsxwriter, xlutils

(My ultimate purpose is to `append clickable cells to existing XLSX`.)

I use the code below to extract the cell's display value and the hyperlink.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xlsFile='hello.xlsx'
wbook = load_workbook(xlsFile)
wsheet1= wbook.get_sheet_by_name('mysheet')
cell1 = wsheet1.cell('A1')

print cell1.value
print cell1.hyperlink
print wsheet1['A1'].value
print wsheet1['A1'].hyperlink
```

But it returns the following things:

```
URL1
None
URL1
None
```

Why the `hyperlink` always `None`? I did add hyperlink manually for cell A1 and the hyperlink works in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unfortunately, it's a bug.

It's a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/152/hyperlink-returns-empty-string-instead-of) in 2012...

Some related thread:

[Extracting Hyperlinks From Excel (.xlsx) with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676727/extracting-hyperlinks-from-excel-xlsx-with-python)

Some details of my experiment with hyperlink. I am using `OpenPyXL 2.3.3`.

1. I can **add hyperlink** to cells.

> ```
> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>
> xlsFile='hello.xlsx'
> wbook = load_workbook(xlsFile)
> wsheet1= wbook.get_sheet_by_name('mysheet')
> cell1 = wsheet1.cell('A1')
> cell1.hyperlink = r'http://www.example.com'
> cell1.value=r'XXX'
> wbook.save(xlsFile)
> ```

2. But I cannot **load the XLSX file and read the hyperlink** just as my question said.
3. And If I just **load and re-save the XLSX file**, ALL existing hyperlinks will be lost. *Yeah!*

> ```
> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>
> xlsFile='hello.xlsx'
> wbook = load_workbook(xlsFile)
> wbook.save(xlsFile)
> ```

### A workaround!

[Use the formula with OpenPyXL](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/usage.html#using-formulae).

My purpose is to `append clickable cells to existing XLSX file`. Since `hyperlink` doesn't work. I use the formula `=HYPERLINK(url, displayText)` instead. And luckily, the formula is not lost like previous experiment 3.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xlsFile='hello.xlsx'
wbook = load_workbook(xlsFile)
wsheet1= wbook.get_sheet_by_name('mysheet')
cell1 = wsheet1.cell('A2')
cell1.value=r'=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com","XXX")'
wbook.save(xlsFile)
```

### Other (*failed*) options I tried:

I looked into the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). But it explicitly says [it cannot modify existing XLSX file](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html). So it cannot be used for appending.

I also looked into the `xlrd/xlwt/xlutils`, unfortunately, if you want to edit an existing excel, you have to use xlrd to load it as a read-only workbook, and then use xlutils to convert(copy) it into a writable workbook. And BANG! during the copy, something will be lost which includes the `HYPERLINK` formula. According to its doc string, this is a known limitation:

```
# Copyright (c) 2009-2012 Simplistix Ltd
#
# This Software is released under the MIT License:
# http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html
# See license.txt for more details.

from xlutils.filter import process,XLRDReader,XLWTWriter

    def copy(wb):
        """
        Copy an :class:`xlrd.Book` into an :class:`xlwt.Workbook` preserving as much
        information from the source object as possible.

        See the :doc:`copy` documentation for an example.
        """
        w = XLWTWriter()
        process(
            XLRDReader(wb,'unknown.xls'),
            w
            )
        return w.output[0][1]
```

And also, xlwt doesn't support XLSX, only supports XLS. That's another reason I decided not to use it.