# Read Excel file which has one of the column as Hyperlink through python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have to read an Excel file Using python. By the time I use

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("abc.xlsx")
```

The column values which had hyperlink assigned to it becomes a simple number without any hyperlink.

Is there any way that I can retain the Hyperlink?

Details below.

[image]

Comment: Obviously you use `pandas` for reading in data from an excel sheet - and the data content is '123', 'abc' and so on. If you want to get more information about the internals of the file, you should use an Excel reader/writer-library like openpyxl or xlrd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting Hyperlinks From Excel (.xlsx) with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676727/extracting-hyperlinks-from-excel-xlsx-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas library does not have the functionality to parse hyperlink as of yet. You could preprocess the excel using libraries such as `xlrd` or `openpxyl` to get hyperlinks then use it in pandas.

> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446810/7570485

There is also a feature request for this functionality.

> https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13439

Comment: This Solution gives me the perfect output but I am not getting the details for all the Hyperlinks. I am looking into that. But I have got the logic. Thank you for your help.