# pandas to_excel removes hyperlink in cells

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I created an excel file using openpyxl which has some hyperlinks using the following command:

=HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(link, "Link Name")

But when I use pandas to sort and then save the excel file. the hyperlinks are gone.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Such formulae make no sense in a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: the type `object` which saves string in pandas is not the same as regular strings, and you don't have string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy

I think this could be useful for you

Cheers

[Read Excel file which has one of the column as Hyperlink through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945110/read-excel-file-which-has-one-of-the-column-as-hyperlink-through-python)

Comment: The problem is that I have a list that is appended as a row so I can't target specify cells as in ws.cell(row=2, column=1).hyperlink