# Extract multiple hyperlinks from a cell of xlsx file using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

If a cell contains multiple hyperlinks, the approach mentioned in the following link doesn't work:
[Extracting Hyperlinks From Excel (.xlsx) with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676727/extracting-hyperlinks-from-excel-xlsx-with-python)

Is there any way to extract multiple hyperlinks in a cell preferably using openpyxl library?

[image: A cell with multiple hyperlinks]

Comment: So do you mean you want the hyperlink from shape(s) placed over the text in the cell rather than from the cell itself?

Answer (score 1):

If it is done by shapes, I don't know of any other way to have multiple hyperlinks in the same cell, then Openpyxl cannot do. Have to use Xlwings.

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

for shape in ws.api.Shapes:
    print(f'Hyperlink: {shape.Hyperlink.Address}')
```

[xlwings](/questions/tagged/xlwings)

Comment: This one doesn't extract multiple hyperlinks in one cell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I'm using CentOS, xlwings doesn't work for xlsx files on Linux.

Comment: I see your problem, but Openpyxl doesn't have much support for shapes. However you haven't confirmed if this is indeed what you are attempting to obtain in case the links are created in some other way. Shapes is the only way I know to do it, and looks like it from the image, but in case this is something different, need to be sure we are looking at the same thing.